# Output of SQL query and command to a file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron

I have the following shell script which runs a SQL query and a command  which sends the output as an email. The issue is I am able to send only the SQL output. Not the output of the for loop. I tried to give the "EOF" after the for loop but then it gives a syntax error. Please let me know how to send both the output in an email.

Thanks & Regards,
Akhil

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.bash_profile

cd /home/cron

wfVAR="red blue green"


echo " " > /home/cron/output.lst
sqlplus -s user/test@DB <<EOF
set linesize 55 pages 500
spool output_temp.lst;
set head off;
select sysdate from dual;
set head on;
spool off;
EOF

for name in ${wfVAR}; do
  pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv REPOSITORY ${name} | grep -e "Workflow:" -e "Workflow run status:" -e "End time:"
 done

sed -e 's/ *$//' output_temp.lst > output.lst
cat /home/cron/output.lst | mail -s "Output - `date '+%d-%m-%y'`" akhil@gmail.com
rm output_temp.lst
```

Comment: As an aside, there is rarely any need to `cd` into the directory, and making the script depend on the invoking user's `.bash_profile` is usually not a good idea at all.  And as ever, `cat file | mail` is better expressed `mail <file`.

Comment: You are not creating `output_temp.lst` and you are not capturing the output from either `sqlplus` or `pmcmd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the file.

```
echo moo >output.lst
echo bar >output.lst
```

Now, `output.lst` only contains `bar`.

The trick is to append, instead of overwrite.

```
echo moo >output.lst
echo bar >> output.lst
```

Your script has multiple additional problems, so it is not really clear what you actually want it to do.  I'm guessing something like this.

```
sql things >output.lst
for var in things; do stuff; done | sed 's/ *$//' >>output.lst
```

... which coincidentally could also be done with a single redirection if you wanted to, by running the commands in a subshell, and redirecting output from the subshell:

```
( sql things
  for var in things; do stuff; done | sed 's/ *$//' ) >output.lst
```

With these speculations, your entire script could be

```
#!/bin/bash
# source $HOME/.bash_profile   ######## XXX probably don't do this

output=/home/cron/output.lst

sqlplus -s user/test@DB <<EOF >$output   # Capture output from SQL
set linesize 55 pages 500
spool output_temp.lst;
set head off;
select sysdate from dual;
set head on;
spool off;
EOF

for name in red blue green; do
  pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv REPOSITORY "$name"
done |
grep -e "Workflow:" -e "Workflow run status:" -e "End time:" |
# XXX: could benefit from refactoring grep x | sed y to just sed '/x/!d;y'
sed -e 's/ *$//' >> $output
# XXX: fixed Useless Use of cat Award
mail -s "Output - `date '+%d-%m-%y'`" akhil@gmail.com <$output
```

Even the permanent output file could be avoided if you like; just pipe to `mail`.

```
#!/bin/bash

( sqlplus -s user/test@DB <<__EOF
    set linesize 55 pages 500
    spool output_temp.lst;
    set head off;
    select sysdate from dual;
    set head on;
    spool off;
__EOF

  for name in red blue green; do
    pmcmd getworkflowdetails -sv REPOSITORY "$name"
  done |
  sed -e '/Workflow:\|Workflow run status:\|End time:/!d' -e 's/ *$//' ) |

mail -s "Output - `date '+%d-%m-%y'`" akhil@gmail.com
```

(... assuming your `sed` understands `\|` to mean alternation in a regex).

Comment: Hi Tripleee, The issue is only the SQL output is coming in the email. I want the output of the for loop also in the same file.

Comment: The answer does that, and explains why your code was wrong. But the code you posted doesn't behave exactly like you describe.  We can only assume that what you posted isn't exactly the code you are running, or that there are some details which you are not telling us (such as if the code is run by a cron job, which sends an email of its standard output and standard error).

Comment: Thanks Triplee, It worked. Earlier I haven't executed the code you have written. Appreciate your help.